# get the multiple checked value from select tag using multiple="true"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

```
   <Select id="chkProduct" multiple="true">
   </select>


   <script type="text/javascript">

         $(function () {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           url: 'http://###.##.##.##/####/Country.svc/ProductBind',
            data: '{}',
            dataType: "json",
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
            var oi;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Data.length; i++) {
                appendString = "<option value='"+data.Data[i].Product+"'>"+data.Data[i].Product +"</option>";
                $("#chkProduct").append(appendString);
            }

         },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });

    });
});

</script>
```

i need some suggestion how can i get the checked value after binding the data..

this dropdown bind checkbox with default OK AND CANCLE button and on OK cleck i get single checked value instead if multiple checked value...
it allow to select multiple check but it take single checked item value...and i want multiple checked value

Comment: This Answer is already available look at here : 
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075842/jquery-sets-multiple-dropdown-options-to-selected>

Comment: dude what you saying is not according to my need.. i have dynamic value with multiple checkbox...

Answer (score 0):

For a multiple select, the .val() returns an array of the selected values (not text). Here is an example:

Given an empty select and a button we'll click to get the selected values

```
<select name="chkProduct" id="chkProduct" multiple="true" data-native-menu="false">
</select>

<button id="btnGet">Get Selected</button>
```

The script loads some options on pagecreate (this would be your ajax function) and then the click handler displays the selected values as a comma delimited list:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){        
    var appendString = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
         appendString += "<option value='"+ i +"'>item "+ i +"</option>";
    }    
    $("#chkProduct").empty().append(appendString).selectmenu( "refresh" );

    $("#btnGet").on("click", function(){
        alert($("#chkProduct").val());
    });
});
```

> Here is a working **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/BTye2/1/)**